# Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jackson-databind

when I'm going to make a request to my api  i got this erros: 
i try to found some question about it but not found any quaestion and answer that can aplicate in my case, i hope one of your can do that for me.

```
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->digifred.arrecadacao.producaoPrimaria.model.Produtos["produtoPrincipal"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:269) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:879) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:666) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
```

i use Spring boot aplication and angularJs in the front end .. look at my code:

my request to api:

```
carregarProdutos = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/user/produtos'              
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.produtos = response.data;
            $scope.idEntidade = response.data[0].entidade.idEntidade;
            $scope.nomeEntidade = response.data[0].entidade.nome;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    };
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/produtos")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Produtos>> buscarTodosProdutos(HttpServletRequest request) throws  Exception { 

        String idEntidadeCrypt = request.getHeader("DataBase");
        Long idEntidade = Long.parseLong(Crypto.decode(idEntidadeCrypt));

        Collection<Produtos> buscados = proService.buscarFiltro(idEntidade);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(buscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and my class model:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "aud", value = "arr_produtos")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "produtos", schema = "arr")
public class Produtos implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4211612266058833945L;


    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidade")
    @ManyToOne(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL*/)
    private Entidades entidade;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_produto")
    private Long idProduto;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codigo_chave")
    private String codigoChave;



    @Column(name = "abreviatura")
    private String abreviatura;



    @JoinColumn(name = "id_produto_principal")
    @ManyToOne
    private  Produtos produtoPrincipal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of the error is confusing you? The `produtoPrincipal` field references the object itself, i.e. `x.produtoPrincipal = x`.

When you export to JSON, that becomes an unending JSON:

```
{
  "idProduto": 1,
  "produtoPrincipal": {
    "idProduto": 1,
    "produtoPrincipal": {
      "idProduto": 1,
      "produtoPrincipal": {
        "idProduto": 1,
        "produtoPrincipal": ...
```

Either:

1. Fix the data so it doesn't reference itself.
2. Figure out what you want the JSON to be when it does, then change code accordingly, e.g. don't include full `Produtos` object for the "principal", just the identifier:

   ```
   {
     "idProduto": 1,
     "idProdutoPrincipal": 1
   }
   ```